# Default front page's url?

Tags: drupal

I don't know much about Drupal, but I know that the default front page shows recent posts.  I would like that feature, but not have it as my front page.  I have the front page set to a different page that tells about the site (a welcome page), but I want another link that shows the recent posts like the regular homepage.  I have no clue how to do this.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default front page is `index.php?q=node`. You can create a menu entry that links to the drupal path `node` to be able to navigate to that page.